# Maven clean install freezes on "Copying artifact" for an EAR with a WAR inside it on Windows

Tags: java, maven, war, ear

Every time I try to run mvn clean install on my EAR, it copies my EJB just fine, but the WAR freezes while trying to copy it to the EAR.

Both the EJB and the WAR build fine, and then I build the EAR and the EJB get's copied fine but then I get this freeze and the console will just sit there forever.

I am using Windows and Java 8 and everything was working fine until at about 10pm last night. Then, freeze. Now, freeze every time.

I have tried deleting my .m2, checking file permissions, nothing seems to work.

Could there be a circular reference or something? I don't think there is.

Is there a way to run mvn verbose for this particular function?

Here is my EAR pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion> 
    <artifactId>my-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-program</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </parent>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skinnyWars>true</skinnyWars>
                    <displayName>${tbs.name}</displayName>
                    <modules>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>my-ejb</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>my-services</artifactId>
                            <contextRoot>/</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>ejb</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>my-services</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And here is the output for the installing phase that freezes:

```
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ my-services ---
[INFO] Installing D:\Development\Projects\my-program\my-services\target\my-services-4.0.war to C:\Users\Me\.m2\repository\com\group\my-services\4.0\my-services-4.0.war
[INFO] Installing D:\Development\Projects\my-program\my-services\pom.xml to C:\Users\Me\.m2\repository\com\group\4.0\my-services-4.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-ear 4.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ my-ear ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\Development\Projects\my-program\my-ear\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.9.1:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) @ my-ear
---
[INFO] Generating application.xml
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ my-ear ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Development\Projects\my-program\my-ear\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-ear-plugin:2.9.1:ear (default-ear) @ my-ear ---
[INFO] Copying artifact [ejb:com.group:my-ejb:4.0] to [my-ejb-4.0.jar]
[INFO] Building zip: D:\Development\Projects\my-program\my-ear\target\my-ear\my-ejb-4.0.jar
[INFO] Copying artifact [war:com.group:my-services:4.0] to [my-services-4.0.war]
```

This is the point at which it just stops forever.

Comment: Did you try rebooting?  Try deleting the entire target folder as well.  Maybe some other process is holding a resource Maven needs.

Comment: Rebooted and manually deleted all target files more times than I can count. Not running Netbeans or any other IDE. Basically, I boot up, open a terminal, and run mvn clean install with nothing else running to try to prevent that process conflict.

Comment: Please run with -X (debug) mode and post the mvn output

Comment: Very important question: Which Maven version do you use? Cause you have weird mixture of old a new versions of plugins in your build?

Comment: Version 3.0.5. Don't know why but I didn't even think of upgrading Maven. Interestingly enough. If I run with -X, the build works fine. If I run without it, it freezes.

Comment: Was there a solution to this?

Comment: I am facing this issue after updating maven install plugin from 2.4 to 2.5.2, so I would suggest for you to try to downgrade, which is not the nicest solution, but anyways.